# How can I solve "Media change: please insert the disc labeled"?

Tags: 20.04, npm

When I run

```
sudo apt install npm
```

I get:

```
Media change: please insert the disc labeled                                   
 'Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731)'
in the drive '/cdrom/' and press [Enter]
```